# How to make a div tag show when you click on a image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a div tag to appear when you click on a picture. I have used jquery to toggle between the two but it isnt working. I think it is to do with the css that i have used. I put it all on js fiddle. 
This is the div that i want to show.

```
<div >
<p class="dinnerplates" style="background-color:#69a0d0;">blurb about vintage plates.blurb about vintage plates.blurb about vintage plates.blurb about vintage plates.blurb about vintage plates.blurb about vintage plates.</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/otbhffeh/

Comment: There's a syntax error in your javascript. Otherwise the logic is fine. Have a look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/otbhffeh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and include jquery too.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".dinnerplates").hide();

// Tooltip only Text
$('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
        // Hover over code
       var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
        .text(title)
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
        // Hover out code
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
        $('.tooltip').remove();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
        $('.tooltip')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })

});
$(".masterTooltip").click(function() {
    $(".dinnerplates").toggle();
});
});
```

Comment: this sort of works but it no longer allows the title to appear on hover

Comment: try now i had deleted  var title = $(this).attr('title') unintentionally when post here